# How to plot CDF in R

Tags: r, distribution, probability, cdf

I am trying to plot a CDF plot using `ecdf()` function using the following code:

```
> x<-ecdf(data$V6)

> summary(x)
 Empirical CDF:   2402 unique values with summary
 Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 3392     71870    120100    386100    219000 158600000 

plot(x, log='x')
    Error in plot.window(...) : Logarithmic axis must have positive limits
```

My dataset grows exponentially so I want to have log scale on x axis. When I don't use `log="x"` it works but the plot is not good. I need the x axis to be logarithmic. Any ideas?

Comment: btw I tried adding `xlim=c(0,158600000)` but another error occured: `nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,8.2003,1, .); log=1]` .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is some code that reproduces your problem:

```
x <- seq(2e3, 1e9, length.out=2000)
ex <- ecdf(x)
plot(ex, log="x")
Error in plot.window(...) : Logarithmic axis must have positive limits
```

Now, set the plot limits to `c(0, 1e9)`

```
plot(ex, xlim=c(0, 1e9), log="x")
Warning message:
In plot.window(...) : nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,9,1, .); log=1]
Warning messages:
1: nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,9,1, .); log=1] 
2: nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,9,1, .); log=1]
```

**The solution:** set the xlim to `c(1, 1e9)`, i.e. set the lower limit to a positive number:

```
plot(ex, xlim=c(1, 1e9), log="x")
```

[image]